# RxJava operators to Kotlin Coroutines using throttleLatest, distinctUntilChanged

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, kotlin-coroutines

What's the best way to convert this RxJava chain to Kotlin Coroutines ?

```
RxTextView
    .textChanges(inputEditText)
    .map { it.toString() }
    .throttleLatest(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, true)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .subscribe({ text ->
        // More logic here
    }, { error ->
        // Error handling
    })
```

Comment: How do you propose to convert the `throttleLatest()` operator? That would be hard to do with a coroutine.

Comment: @BobDalgleish I saw an article not long ago which showed how easy it was to rewrite RxJava operators using Kotlin Coroutines but can't find it anymore. Maybe someone can post the link here.

Answer (score 0):

There's a related open issue on GitHub where a solution is proposed using existing operators:

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.throttleLatest(delayMillis: Long): Flow<T> = this
    .conflate()
    .transform {
        emit(it)
        delay(delayMillis)
    }
```

https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1446#issuecomment-1198103541

There's also a library which is working similar to the RxJava `throttleLatest` function.
This is the function documentation https://hoc081098.github.io/FlowExt/docs/latest/-flow-ext/com.hoc081098.flowext/throttle-time.html

Library providing different RxJava operators
https://github.com/hoc081098/FlowExt